Is 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 the Object Identifier OID of AWS KMS signing algo RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256, re ASN.1 CSR syntax
I have been looking for a chart the gives the OID corresponding to Amazon signing algorithms. I have not found this level of detail in AWS docs.
I plan to use the key for signing a Certificate Request, e.g. with AWS algorithm RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256.  I am building the ASN.1 syntax at a low level.
I am guessing that this RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256 algorithm uses both PSS and SHA256. That is why I am not sure which OID should be used to identify it, in a Certificate Request CSR.

Based on PSS, I come up with OID 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10, rsassa-pss.
Based on SHA256, I come up with OID 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11,
sha256WithRSAEncryption.

Both might be wrong!
Clarity from someone with insight into AWS KMS and OIDs would be greatly appreciated.

OIDs with names of the form {hash}withRSAEncryption (not just {hash}) as listed in PKCS1 A.2.4 are RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 schemes, not RSASSA-PSS. (pkcs-1 is defined in C as 1.2.840.113549.1.1; note you want the lowercase one not the uppercase one which is the module)

AWS offers these choices for the signing algorithm, all uppercase:
RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_256,
RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_384,
RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_512,
RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256,
RSASSA_PSS_SHA_384,
RSASSA_PSS_SHA_512

AWS DOES have docs about the key signing algorithm here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/asymmetric-key-specs.html

The OID for the AWS KMS signature algorithm RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 https://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.2.840.113549.1.1.10.html    The OID for the public key itself was contained within the public key itself, namely 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1
rsaEncryption PKCS #1 and that can be seen immediately by loading just the public key into https://lapo.it/asn1js/

The OID repository shows 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 parses to {iso(1) member-body(2) us(840) rsadsi(113549) pkcs(1) pkcs-1(1) rsassa-pss(10)} and is thus for rsassa-pss, and is also for id-RSASSA-PSS. That stands for the signature scheme RSASSA-PSS of PKCS#1.
Missing for an actual signature scheme are RSASSA-PSS parameters:

the hash (typically SHA-256, SHA-384 or SHA-512 in modern use)
the mask generating function (in practice always MGF1) and it's parameters (for MGF1: typically the same hash as above, or SHA-1 which is the default in some APIs, including that of Java, see this).
the salt length (it's typically 0, or 20, or the width of the output of the hash algorithm e.g. 32 for SHA-256)
the trailer field (typically 0xBC)

The OID for SHA-256 is 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1
The OID for MGF1 is 1.2.840.113549.1.1.8
Recommendations for describing RSASSA-PSS parameters are in RFC 4055 section 3 and the structure for that is explained in 3.1 RSASSA-PSS Public Keys:
   When RSASSA-PSS is used in an AlgorithmIdentifier, the parameters
   MUST employ the RSASSA-PSS-params syntax.  The parameters may be
   either absent or present when used as subject public key information.
   The parameters MUST be present when used in the algorithm identifier
   associated with a signature value.

   When signing, it is RECOMMENDED that the parameters, except for
   possibly saltLength, remain fixed for all usages of a given RSA key
   pair.

      RSASSA-PSS-params  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
         hashAlgorithm      [0] HashAlgorithm DEFAULT
                                   sha1Identifier,
         maskGenAlgorithm   [1] MaskGenAlgorithm DEFAULT
                                   mgf1SHA1Identifier,
         saltLength         [2] INTEGER DEFAULT 20,
         trailerField       [3] INTEGER DEFAULT 1  }

Note 1: SHA-1 is deprecated and often unsafe as hashAlgorithm, but MGF1 with SHA-1 remains safe.
Note 2: the value 1 in trailerField means trailedFieldBC that is a trailer field of 0xBC. Don't ever dare using anything else.
I welcome a description of what a certificate or CSR must actually contain!

I have found RFC 2986 at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2986 from year 2000 to be helpful in describing the CSR requirements.  In practice thus far, I have only seen ASN.1 "null" which is hex 05 00 as the Algorithm parameters for OID 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5.

I have been using the ASN.1 JavaScript decoder at https://lapo.it/asn1js/ to analyze the contents of CSR files. It has some sample files you can try including a certification request.  Load a sample, and then you can see the ASN.1 elements.  Mouseover the signatureAlgorithm to see corresponding hex highlighted.

OpenSSL can make a key with similar parameters to AWS KMS RSA_4096: openssl.exe genpkey -algorithm rsa-pss    -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096   -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_md:sha256   -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_mgf1_md:sha256   -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_saltlen:32      -out privateOpenKey4096.pem

OpenSSL can generate a CSR with samples values. NB: 32octets means 256bits for the key length. Syntax, assuming you have extracted the PublicKey to PEM already: openssl req -new -key privateOpenKey4096.pem -out MYOpenCSR_SaltLen32.csr

On Windows, both certutil and openssl can be used to verify the contents of a CSR. OpenSSL syntax:  openssl req -text -noout -verify -in 

The AWS KMS signature algorithm RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256 requires non-default parameters.  Use OID 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1
to indicate sha-256 NIST Algorithm   and   OID 1.2.840.113549.1.1.8 to indicate
pkcs1-MGF PKCS #1    and Integer 32 for the saltLength in octets.
